# Installing password protected network printer in Python with win32print

Tags: python, authentication, printing, python-2.7

I am trying to connect to/install a network printer on my local machine through Python 2.7 and the win32print module. When attempting to connect to the printer normally (entering the IP address of the server in the Windows Start menu) I am prompted to enter my username and password.

In the Python shell, when I enter:

`win32print.AddPrinterConnection(r'\\myserver\\myprinter')`

I get:

`error: (1326, 'AddPrinterConnection', 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.')`

How do I submit the login and password forms? Once I've successfully connected to the printer, how do I actually install it on my computer?

EDIT: Although I am more concerned with installing the printer in general, I am also interested with how I would go about this in Python.

Comment: Why are you using Python to add a printer to your computer?

Comment: In short, I want a program I can use to automatically install a printer. Would I be better off using another language?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754632%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that I'd like to do this on Windows 7. This looks like it only applies to Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008.